# Filter some parameters at logging-channel-adapter in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

Headers object has series of parameters and one of them is a list of another parameters. some parameters are secured and I don't want to log them. how can I filter their parameters **only in this channel** ?

```
<integration:logging-channel-adapter channel="logChannel" level="INFO" expression="'message received, headers:' + headers"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `header-filter` upstream of the logging adapter to remove any headers you don't want logged.